# Can't read property of undefined when trying to grab a channel in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to send a message to a specific channel using discord.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);

const channel = client.channels.cache.get("831148754181816351");
channel.send("working");
```

Error message:

```
home/fahd/Desktop/Dev/DiscordBot/main.js:7
channel.send("working");
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fahd/Desktop/Dev/DiscordBot/main.js:7:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I tried using changing the location of client.login() to the end of the file.
I tried using `channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "831148754181816351");` instead but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested out your code as-is and this means that the `channels` collection it is trying to retrieve is empty.

What you have to do instead is put it inside a client event listener. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060616/discord-js-without-using-client-eventemitter-cannot-get-channels-property), I learned that the compiler will always run the code outside of the client EventEmitters first before the bot is able to log in. The most convenient option (because it looks like you want this to be triggered automatically when the bot is on) is to use the `ready` event listener.

Example Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
require('dotenv').config();

client.on('ready', () => {
    const channelID = '831148754181816351'; //this is your channelID
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
    channel.send('working'); //this works :)
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Yup no problem.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox Sorry! I rejected your _retagging_ edit suggested to the question, because the question is clearly about the Javascript library `discord.js` and its proper usage, not `discord` as API itself (see both tag descriptions and distinguishing notes there). Anyway ️ for your answer.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for letting me know! I commonly see [discord.js] paired with [discord] tag so that's why I put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not getting the channel you want. Try using the `.fetch()` method. Since it returns a `promise`you also need to `await` it.

It then should look like this:

```
const channelID = '831148754181816351';
const targetChannel = await message.client.channels.fetch(channelID);

// work with 'targetChannel'
```