# Discord.js - Without using Client EventEmitter cannot get channels property

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I still have yet to get a better grasp of Node.js, but as I was tinkering around with my Discord bot, I couldn't seem to find a way to get the list of channels the bot was in without putting it in an EventEmitter. I'm rather confused as to why this wouldn't work, is there something that I'm missing?

Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
require('dotenv').config();

//this works
client.on('ready', ()=> {
    const channelID = '803359668054786118';
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
    channel.send('working'); //this works
});

//this doesn't work
//intially tried using a wait function to see if the reason was because bot didn't have enough time to log on properly
setTimeout(function() {
    const channelID = '803359668054786118';
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
    console.log(client.channels); //this is telling me that there's no channels in the collection...
    //channel.send('working');
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the **client is not logged in** at that point of your code. At the compile stage of your file, the compiler runs through your code and compiles everything outside of event listeners. Once `Client#login()` is called, this is when the client has it's context. All of it's event listeners (*ready, message ect.*) are binded to the client.

In other words, the Discord client is not logged in when code *outside of events* being is compiled. Code inside events are executed once the client is logged in & the event itself is emitted.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it wait until the client is logged in before it gets compiled? I tried to do it with the `setTimeout` function but from what you're saying it won't work that way.

Comment: Sadly not, the compiler will run through your code regardless. Is there a specific reason as to not use the ready event?

Comment: Mainly to not have to use an EventEmitter. This was more of a conceptual question anyways, so thanks!